# Sorting on numerical value in stacked histogram in SPSS GGRAPH GPL

Tags: spss, ggraph

How can I have this graph (Stacked Histogram) sorted on the variable MEAN(RowN) or MEAN(RowN_A) or MEAN(RowN_B) instead of on Var1?

Stacked Histogram [Stacked Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1vjx.png)

What I have tried so far: sorting the data in the dataset
Variations of sort.values in the GPL SCALE command.

Below the code:

```
* Custom Tables.
CTABLES
  /VLABELS VARIABLES=Var1 RowN RowN_A RowN_B DISPLAY=LABEL
  /TABLE Var1 BY RowN [MEAN] + RowN_A [MEAN] + RowN_B [MEAN]
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=Var1 ORDER=D KEY=VALUE EMPTY=EXCLUDE
  /CRITERIA CILEVEL=95
  /TITLES
    TITLE='Percentages favorable, neutral, unfavorable'.

* Chart Builder.
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Var1 MEAN(RowN) MEAN(RowN_A) MEAN(RowN_B) 
    MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
    TRANSFORM=VARSTOCASES(SUMMARY="#SUMMARY" INDEX="#INDEX")
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE
  /COLORCYCLE COLOR1(225,188,29), COLOR2(161,24,80), COLOR3(63,235,124), COLOR4(79,33,150), 
    COLOR5(0,158,154), COLOR6(0,114,195), COLOR7(208,176,255), COLOR8(0,97,97), COLOR9(250,117,166), 
    COLOR10(0,60,115), COLOR11(169,112,255), COLOR12(209,39,101), COLOR13(108,202,255), 
    COLOR14(110,50,201), COLOR15(1,186,182), COLOR16(118,11,57), COLOR17(17,147,232), 
    COLOR18(0,125,121), COLOR19(255,160,194), COLOR20(137,63,252)
  /FRAME OUTER=NO INNER=NO
  /GRIDLINES XAXIS=NO YAXIS=YES
  /STYLE GRADIENT=NO.
BEGIN GPL
  DATA: SUMMARY=col(source(s), name("#SUMMARY"))
  DATA: INDEX=col(source(s), name("#INDEX"), unit.category())
  COORD: rect(dim(1,2), transpose())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Var1"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Mean"))
  GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), label(""))
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0))
  SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), reverse(), include("0", "1", "2"))
  ELEMENT: interval.stack(position(Var1*SUMMARY), color.interior(INDEX),           shape.interior(shape.square))
```

END GPL.